# C# Input string was not in a correct format localhost

Tags: c#, iis-7.5

I'm quite a beginner in C# and now I've this problem to recover the ip address of my localhost web.

CS:

```
LocalIp = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

Response.Write("IP Address: " + LocalIp.ToString());
Response.End();
```

I wait 127.0.0.1 but in output I've:

```
IP Address: ::1
```

What shall I do? The version of IIS is 7.5 in windows 7.
Thank in advance,

**EDIT:**
Solved with take a look at the default Windows hosts file, at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (open with notepad)`
In previous versions of Windows, we find the following active entry for **"localhost"**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

But in Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2, the hosts file is effectively empty. While there are both IPv4 and IPv6 entries for "localhost", both are disabled by being commented out.

```
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost
```

I've enabled and now all working.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an IPv6 address. If the connection was made with IPv6, then that is the value you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. `::1` is the [ipv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) way of saying `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the ::1 is the correct IPv6 address of your localhost. You were expecting the IPv4 version. Take a look at this article over at 4guysfromrolla.com:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102847/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071807-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. May be It will help you.

```
        IPAddress[] localIPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress Addr in localIPs)
        {                
            if (Addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                Response.Write("IP Address: " + Addr );
            }
        }
```